# Haskell Interactive

Tags: shell, emacs, ide, haskell, interpreter

I am a bit rusty on my Haskell and am looking to ramp back up. One thing I enjoy from F# is the F# Interactive shell integrated with Visual Studio: I can evaluate virtually anything (including function and class definitions) and use F# as a shell. Is there an equivalent in Haskell? When I use `ghci`, I cannot evaluate function definitions. How do you work around that?

My current preferred setting is using Emacs with haskell-mode and opening an interactive ghi interpreter. However, is there a way to evaluate just region of a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a function using 'let':

```
$ ghci
Prelude> let double n = n + n
Prelude> double 42
84
```

Also, I won't quite recommend this, since (A) I wrote it, and (B) it's terribly undeveloped, but [Halp](http://github.com/darius/halp/) can be handy in Emacs -- it's a little bit like a spreadsheet for Haskell code integrated right into your source-code buffer. You can have a set of expressions you're interested in and with one keystroke see how all their values change depending on your edits  since the last reevaluation.

Comment: Thanks. Halp looks indeed handy. I'll be trying it out :)

Comment: Cool! Improvements would be welcome -- the Python version is more polished because I use Python more.

Answer (score 3):

As you've observed, GHCi is fairly limited in what it can do --- short functions or expressions are about all that's easy at the command line.  For the rest I find myself loading modules.  One of the difficulties is that **Haskell does not have definition before use** so it is often hard to pull a meaningful fragment out of a file.  I generally find myself defining small modules and loading and reloading them.  The interactive experience is definitely not as nice as one might like.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell mode for Emacs provide functions for work with intepreter. So if you want to run some function from the module that you edit, you can use C-c C-l to load current module to ghci (or another haskell interactive) and switch to buffer with interactive and execute some commands there

Answer (score 1):

ghci provides some special syntax for doing things like that. Use `let` for function definitions. However, it's noted on the [GHC FAQ](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC:FAQ) that it can be tricky with complex functions and generally loading from a file is preferred. If you use something like Emacs that allows for easy integration between your source file and a ghci process, it becomes a non-issue because you can load your definitions into the interpreter with a keystroke.

Comment: In Emacs, is there a way to load a region of a file as opposed to the entire file?

Comment: No, here are the haskell-mode ghci commands:

haskell-ghci-load-file             haskell-ghci-mode
haskell-ghci-reload-file           haskell-ghci-show-ghci-buffer
haskell-ghci-start-process

You just get load/reload support.

Answer (score 0):

With O'Caml and F#, definitions proceed from the top of the file down. However, in Haskell, a type or function defined earlier in a file can reference a type or function later in that file. So in Haskell, a module needs to be compiled all at once. An interactive loop is incompatible with compilation all-at-once.

Answer (score 0):

Flymake combined with Emacs Haskell Mode 2.8 works very well and you get an immediate response of the type checker. In my eyes this is more interactive.